# Prove that this allocation is fair without direct computation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let there be $n$ offices in a circle and $n$ people to fill them (one office each, of course). There are three people who really must have adjacent offices since they're good friends, and furthermore the first three offices are nicer. Design a randomized allocation algorithm that always gives these three employees adjacent offices while making sure everyone (including these three) has an equal chance of getting one of the nicer offices.

---

My algorithm is simple. First give three adjacent offices to the group of three, and then randomly allocate the remaining $n-3$ offices.

---

I want to prove that this does indeed give an equal chance of getting one of the nicer offices **without just computing it.** That would mean through, e.g., some symmetric property, or basically any vaguely formalized argument for why this is the case. It seems to "make sense" that it's true, but I want a specific argument as to why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess in "give three adjacent offices to the group of three" you're implying that you uniformly randomly choose among all sets of three adjacent offices.

That algorithm is correct, but that's a bit easier to see if you formulate it slightly differently: Give a certain fixed set of three adjacent offices to the group of three, allocate the remaining $n-3$ offices any way you like (doesn't have to be random), and then rotate the entire arrangement (say, clockwise) by a uniformly randomly chosen number of offices between $0$ and $n-1$. The last step in itself is enough to make sure that everyone has the same chance of getting any given office. Now you just have to convince yourself that this has exactly the same effect as what you proposed.

Comment: The process of allocating a fixed three offices, then the rest, and **then** rotating has sold me that the probability is random.